# Обработка матрицы

Tags: массивы, pascal, матрицы, алгоритм

Составить программу для обработки матрицы A(m,n), где m,n<=7. Размер матрицы задается при вводе. Сформировать новый массив из элементов строк матрицы, которые располагаются ниже строки с минимальным элементом всей матрицы. Вывести сформированный массив и исходную матрицу в виде матрицы.

Как задать в паскале размер матрицы при вводе, если размер двумерного массива должен быть железно задан в константе?

Comment: В паскале -- да. В трубо/борланд-паскале/delphi (и примкнувшем к ним фрипаскале) -- уже нет См. http://www.freepascal.org/docs-html/ref/refsu18.html

(любителям turbopascal'я -- http://www.oldospc.ru/soft/other/trick/trubopascacal/order-name/page-0 )

Answer (score 1):

Ограничения на размер матрицы маленькие, можно объявить матрицу 7 на 7, но использовать только ту её часть, которую укажет пользователь. Если по каким-то причинам это не подходит, есть другие варианты. Если вы пишете на FreePsacal, PascalABC или Delphi, можно использовать [динамические массивы](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/pascal/pascal_dynamic_arrays.htm) (Turbo Pascal их не поддерживает!). В Turbo Pascal можно реализовать динамический двумерный массив на [указателях](http://www.cyberforum.ru/free-pascal/thread387626.html).

Comment: Sorry. Не хотел вводить в заблуждение, заблуждался сам. (Виртовский паскаль был проще и стройней)